# Prove that A is multiples of the identity matrix if and only if for every vector not zero v is an eigenvector of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a matrix of size n × n. Prove that A is
multiples of the identity matrix if and only if for every vector
not zero [image] is an eigenvector of A.

Comment: Could you show what you've thought so far?

Answer (score 1):

One implication is obvious. Now, suppose that for every $x$ there is $\lambda_x$ such that $Ax=\lambda_xx$. We show that $\lambda_x=\lambda_y$ for every $x,y$. Let $x,y$ be linearly independent, then $$\lambda_xx+\lambda_yy=Ax+Ay=A(x+y)=\lambda_{(x+y)}(x+y)=\lambda_{x+y}x+\lambda_{x+y}y\\ \implies (\lambda_x-\lambda_{x+y})x+(\lambda_y-\lambda_{x+y})y=0$$
Since $x,y$ are linearly independent it follow that $\lambda_x=\lambda_{x+y}=\lambda_y$. Can you find how to deal with the case when $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent?